# Creating an interactive rotating image from multiple JPEGs

Tags: terminology, visualization

I am looking to create an interactive image of a machine. I will be taking incremental photos of it rotationally at two different distances from the machine (approx. 20ft and 5ft away).

Once I have all the images taken I will process them for exposure and whatnot.  At this point I will just assume that they will be ".jpg" files. It's the next part that I need some help with:

- I want the website user to be able to click and rotate the machine as well as zoom in and out and pan up and down (similar to Google Earth).
- I would like the series of images to be cycled left and right as the user moves their mouse left and right to give the illusion that is is rotating, but it is in fact simply cycling through the images and essentially giving them control of the "animation effect".
- I am looking for a direction to begin creating this interactive image.  So far I have not been able to find anything other than rotating GIFs or something similar that has no user interaction.

Comment: Sounds as though you need a panorama creator and then a viewer for any web use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally these are referred to as 360 degree virtual tours.

Look that up on your favorite search engine should find a lot of results - some free others for a price.

I added to the query "how to make 360 virtual tour of object instead of room" and that found http://www.360degreeviews.com/ which appears to do exactly what you're looking for based on the little example they have. Not sure if it does the zoom and up down but check it out. And other results from the search query and you can probably find something.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer.  This is exactly what I was looking for.